# How to delay the text function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the text present in a div to another text by using text() function in jQuery. It is working fine but it is too fast. Is there anyway to delay this text() function so that I can view the change properly. Here's the code.Please take a look at it. Thanks in advance :)

```js
$('.main .title').text("Changed title!");
$('.main .description').text("Changed Description");
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="title">
    <p>This title text should be changed</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>This description should als be changed</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function for delay purpose.

```
< script type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(function () {
            $('.main .title').text("Changed title!");
            $('.main .description').text("Changed Description");
        }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I did, but as I have less than 15 reputation it is not accepting :|

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout function..

```
setTimeout(function(){

$('.main').text("Changed title!");

},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main .title').delay(3000).text("Changed title!");
```

Just try jquery's delay function. It should work. Otherwise you can also use Javascript native function `setTimeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main .title').fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).text("Changed title!").fadeIn();
});
```

OR

```
$('.main .title').fadeOut(<delay-here-in-milliseonds>, function() {
      $(this).text("Changed title!").fadeIn();
    });
```

Try this. Using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `setTimeout` .

```
$('.main .title').data("timeout", setTimeout(function () {
      $('.main .title').text("Changed title!");
    }, 2000));
    $('.main .description').data("timeout", setTimeout(function () {
   $('.main .description').text("Changed Description");
    }, 4000));
```

Working Fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/5pjdeupy/)

Comment: Thank you, will there be any difference in using the jquery setTimeout function rather than javascript function? are they both the same?